# How can i implement chart.js destroy in my draw function

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a doughnut Chart that I would like to update with a new dataset each time I select a different option in my dropdown menu but because my code is in a `draw()` function, the chart constantly tries to draw itself over and over again which is why I keep getting the error message:  `Canvas is already in use. Chart with ID '0' must be destroyed before the canvas with ID 'myChart' can be reused.`

How would I be able to fix this? The variable named `stats` is wat I'm trying to update my chart's data with.

```
        var config = {
            type: 'doughnut',
            data: {
                labels: legend,
                datasets: [{
                    backgroundColor: ['rgb(204,0,0)', 'rgb(241,194,50)', 'rgb(41,134,204)', 'rgb(106,168,79)', 'rgb(255,62,153)'],
                    data: stats,
                }]
            },
            plugins: [hoverLabel],
            options: {
                radius: this.radius,
                hoverOffset: 30,
                responsive: true,
                maintainAspectRatio: false,
                plugins: {
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: "Top 5 causes of death in " + country,
                        color: 'rgb(0,0,0)',
                        align: 'center',
                        padding: 15,
                        font: {
                            size: 25
                        }
                    },
                    legend: {
                        position: 'right',
                        title: {
                            display: true,
                            color: 'rgb(0,0,0)',
                            text: 'Legend',
                            font: {
                                weight: 'bold',
                                size: 20
                            },
                        },
                        labels: {
                            color: 'rgb(0,0,0)',
                            usePointStyle: true,
                            padding: 15,
                            font: {
                                size: 15,
                                weight: 'bold'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        };


        let mychart = new Chart('myChart', config);
```

[Doughnut Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5wJSv.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options, either fully recreate the chart by destroying it first:

```js
const config = {}; // Fill with your config opbject

let chart = Chart.getChart('myChart'); // Pass the canvas ID

if (chart) {
  chart.destroy();
}

chart = new Chart('myChart', config);
```

or by updatingt the current chart instance:

```js
const config = {}; // Fill with your config opbject

let chart = Chart.getChart('myChart'); // Pass the canvas ID

if (chart) {
  chart.data.labels = legend;
  chart.data.datasets[0].data = stats;
  chart.update();
} else {
  new Chart('myChart', config)
}
```

Comment: omg the ```.update()``` worked for me!! thank you so much!!